# Calculate the height of body

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HERE'S MY [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/njz87Lth/10/)**

I have one page with different elements. 
These elements are changing them position "fixed" to "absolute" at a certain scroll position.

The problem is my body height. Because of the fixed element, it have no "auto" height on my body. So I putted a a min-height : 1000px for exemple. But its not the right solution...
The size of the scrollbar change while you scrolling and I would like the body cover all my elements.

Maybe I have to calculate at the beginning the height of my body without the fixed elements ?

```
 $('body').css({scrollTop:$(document).height() + $(window).height()});
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').css({
    scrollTop: $(document).height() + $(window).height()
  });

  var windw = this;

  $.fn.followTo = function(pos) {
    var $this = this,
      $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function(e) {
      if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
        $this.css({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: pos
        });
      } else {
        $this.css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: 0
        });
      }
    });
  };

  $('h1').followTo(400);

  $('.two').followTo(350);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your point you want the `body` element to wrap all of your divs in page no matter whether they are positioned with fixed or absolute, is that right?

Well if so you could try with this very hardcoded solution, by calculating the height of the body by adding the heights of each div including also its vertical margins.

So instead of doing this:

```
$('body').css({scrollTop:$(document).height() + $(window).height()});
```

You can do like this:

```
var totalOneHeight = $('.one').height() + parseInt($('.one').css('marginTop'));
var totalTwoHeight = $('.two').height() + parseInt($('.two').css('marginTop'));
var totalHeight = totalOneHeight + totalTwoHeight;
$('body').css({'height': totalHeight});
```

Of course this is a very hardcoded solution, so if you plan to add more content to the page please remember to add the items in the sum.

I use `.css('marginTop')` to get the marginTop for an element, surrounded by `parseInt()` since the previous methods returns also the unit (px).

**EDIT:** just in case you were wondering about, if you add marginBottom you should also put it into the sum

Try the solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/njz87Lth/11/)

Answer (score 0):

i think that this solve your problem

```
#footer {
        padding: 20px 0;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 15000;
    }
```

Comment: i created for you see, the footer always remains  in the same place: 
https://jsfiddle.net/numo43o3/2/#&togetherjs=fjtc0A3PVo